# differences between update column with row number and select

Tags: sql-server

As beginner I want to update a table column with row number and expect an output like;

| id_subjekt | MutNr | RowNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12620 | 30799 | 1 |
| 12620 | 41855 | 1 |
| 12620 | 55555 | 1 |
| 12620 | 55555 | 2 |
| 12620 | 55555 | 3 |

Tried with a select on following code, I get exactly that.

```
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY MutNr
     ORDER BY MutNr
     ) as x
from [dbo].[Nametest]
```

I packed this into following update condition;

```
update
    [dbo].[Nametest]
set
    RowNr = x
from (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY MutNr
        ORDER BY MutNr
        ) as x
    from [dbo].[Nametest]
    ) o
```

output now divers completely from my expectations;

| id_subjekt | MutNr | RowNr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12620 | 30799 | 1 |
| 12620 | 41855 | 3 |
| 12620 | 55555 | 1 |
| 12620 | 55555 | 3 |
| 12620 | 55555 | 1 |

I don't understand why the update divers from the select. May someone explain me the difference / mistake? And maybe as well the correct code? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other possibility is to choose a CommonTableExpression:

```
with RowNrQry
as
(
select *
, row_number() over(partition by MutNr order by MutNr) as x
from dbo.Nametest
)
update RowNrQry
set RowNr = x
go
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing `where` clause.

```
update
    [dbo].[Nametest]
set
    RowNr = x
from (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY MutNr
        ORDER BY MutNr
        ) as x, MutNr
    from [dbo].[Nametest]
    ) o where [Nametest].date =o.MutNr
```

Comment: `MutNr` is also missing in the original inner query. You fixed/added that in your answer, but I wanted to point it out, just in case OP only added your WHERE clause and the query then would throw an error due to the missing inner `MutNr`.

Comment: thank you both a lot for your answer.  I see the points with the missing `MutNr` and the where clause, but not with the `[Nametest].date`.